# How do I remove the autogenerated Html escape entities, and why are they being created

Tags: laravel-5, shopping-cart

I am trying to save the path of the product image from my database to the cart, example,

> /images/menu/uploads/thumb_imageDecliciousCrumpets7579adcb6ca553.jpg,

but when I save the path then try to access it, the image breaks because the path now becomes

> ["/images/menu/uploads/thumb_imageDecliciousCrumpets7579adcb6ca553.jpg"]

My controller code

```
$image=\App\Product_image::where('product_id','=',$request->id)->where('is_featured','=','1')->pluck('thumb_path');

 Cart::add($request->id,$request->title,1,$price,['image'=>$image]);
 return Response::json($image,200);
```

My View Code:

```
@foreach($cart as $cart_item)

    <td class="product-thumbnail">
         <a href="single-product.html"><img width="145" height="145" alt="{{$cart_item->name}}" class="shop_thumbnail" src="{{$cart_item->options->image}}"></a>
      </td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: why you are returning as JSON? are you using ajax based? just try this `return $image;`

Comment: Yes it is ajax based...actually when I return using json, it is returning the correct string, I concluded it is the Cart class that is generating the html entities

Comment: can you show me the result (html entities) which you are getting in response of ajax request?